# host a 500gb mysql database in RAM memory

Tags: mysql, memory

I have a 500gb mysql database.

Assuming that buying RAM is not a problem (memory is cheap), is it practical or even sane to host an entire 500gb mysql database in RAM memoery for faster accessing speeds?

Comment: Unless that's all throwaway data, be very, very careful with your backups & persistence in general. One erroneous shutdown or kill and your data's history. (Obviously UPS and such are also necessary.) Again unless that's all scratch space, use a database with in memory + persistency capabilities.

Comment: it's always a good idea to be careful, but by default InnoDB is durable no matter how much memory you put in or how large database is. A crash may (but not necessary will) destroy your data as long as the redo logs are on the persistent storage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is entirely possible (some) HP Gen 9 servers for example support 1.5TB of RAM which should be ok for a 500GB database.